# Out of sample prediction for multivariate time series using SVM regression

Tags: time-series, machine-learning, svm, forecasting, caret

```
##Data loading 
data(economics)
load(economics)


##Data splitting 
Index <- createDataPartition(economics$unemploy, p = 0.8,list = FALSE, times = 1)
head(Index)


train <- economics[Index, ]
test <-  economics[-Index,]



## SVM - Regression 
svmRbftune <- train(unemploy ~ pce + pop + psavert + uempmed,
            data = train, method = "svmRadial",
            tunelength = 14, trControl = trainControl(method ="cv"))

  ## SVM predict 

  svmpredict<-predict(svmRbftune,test)


  Test <- test$unemploy
  RbfData <- cbind(svmpredict,Test)
  RbfDataM <- as.data.frame(RbfData)
  qplot(svmpredict, Test, data = RbfDataM, geom =c("point", "smooth"))
```

[image]

I want to forecast for 2008 January, February, March. I want to do out of sample forecasting without using the Forecast package

Answer (score 1):

Use `trainControl(method ="cv", savePredictions = TRUE)` then see `svmRbftune$pred`. Note there are also [methods for time series too](http://topepo.github.io/caret/splitting.html#time).

Max